# Django Compressor Blank Css Output File

Tags: python, css, django, compression

When django compresses css it saves the output to a file in /static/CACHE/css/[filename].css, however no matter what I try, the css file keeps coming out blank!

In my template...

```
{% compress css %}
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/less' href='{{ STATIC_URL }}css/deals_for_you.less'/>
{% endcompress %}
```

I installed django_compressor, django_appconf, and versiontools successfully
I installed lessc successfully (testecd)
STATICFILES_FINDERS are set

```
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT = {
    'STATIC_URL': STATIC_URL,
}
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

Also, when I run

```
python manage.py compress
```

It outputs...

```
Found 'compress' tags in:
    [/my/file/path]/index.html
Compressing... done
Compressed 1 block(s) from 1 template(s)
```

But the output file that I get (at /static/CACHE/css/d41d8cd98f00.css)
is always empty!

Comment: What do you have for `COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS`?

Comment: COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = ( ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}),)

^ I added to question, thanks!

Comment: Try setting `COMPRESS_ENABLED` to False, and see what happens. (That will only pass the file to the precompilers and not the filters, so it's an easy way to narrow down the failure candidates). If it works with `COMPRESS_ENABLED` set to false, then there's something wrong with the css filters being run on the file. We can work from there.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, it still doesn't work after setting COMPRESS_ENABLED to False

Comment: And you're sure that `lessc` is working correctly? (You can run `$ lessc path/to/some.less path/to/some.css` at the command line from your project root directory).

Comment: @ChrisPratt yup! `lessc path/to/my.less path/to/my.css` outputs the compiled css to the terminal and writes the file correctly... (you can see why i'm frustrated, haha)

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas, then. With `COMPRESS_ENABLED=False`. The only thing that happens are the commands in `COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS`. You can try filing an issue at https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/issues. Be as specific as possible and post any and all info that might be relevant: versions of Django/django-compressor, system information, python version, etc.

Comment: zconnelly13!!! what did you see??

Answer (score 0):

Did you install via npm or via a ruby gem? If the latter, try updating to:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} > {outfile}'),
)
```

See the issue on this: https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/pull/177