# Local setting for INSTALLED_APPS using Fabric

Tags: django, fabric

I have an app(django-compressor) that I only want to run on my local machine and not the server.  I know about the

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

trick.  But I was wondering if there was a better way to remove the app I only want run locally from the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` using Fabric.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the standard approach you mentioned is best; create a folder `settings` with three settings files; `shared.py`, `production.py` and `development.py`. Settings that are common to all instances of your app are placed in `shared.py` and this is imported from `production.py` and `development.py`. Then you can easily only add `compressor` in your development settings

**shared.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (...)
```

**development.py**

```
from settings.shared import *
INSTALLED_APPS += ('compressor',)
```

You need to make sure then when developing, you run the development server with the `development.py` settings file:

```
python manage.py --settings=settings.development
```

and similarly on your production server you do the same for `production.py` (this is down to your implementation)

This is a much better approach in the long term as you can also specify separate cache, database, search etc. settings too.

**As an aside,** instead of completely removing `compressor` from your installed apps, you can simply enable and disable is using it's `COMPRESS_ENABLED` setting

Comment: thanks for the great answer.  Regarding the `COMPRESSOR_ENABLED` setting, if I set it to FALSE I am still left with templates that have the `{% compress js %}` and `{% endcompress %}` which then break on the server.  Is there a way to make `django-compressor` remake the template files without these tags?  This question I made is about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392993/weird-deployment-issue-with-django-and-coffeescript-to-heroku Thanks for the help on this question and any help on the other questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When `COMPRESSOR_ENABLED = False` (but still in the `INSTALLED_APPS`), those blocks shouldn't cause any error - they should just be ignored.

Comment: Even with `COMPRESS_ENABLED = False` I get `TemplateSyntaxError at /` ... `Caught FilterError while rendering: /bin/sh: coffee: not found`

Comment: I found this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899913/django-compressor-blank-css-output-file "With COMPRESS_ENABLED=False. The only thing that happens are the commands in COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS." I have `COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (('text/coffeescript', 'coffee --compile --stdio'),)`  The issue is that the server tries this and has nothing called coffee.  Hmmmm.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it in another way.

All the shared settings are in settings.py and keep the difference in local_settings. In your case it is INSTALLED_APPS, you can change your import section to something like this:

```
DEV_APPS = None
try:
    from local_settings import *
    INSTALLED_APPS += DEV_APPS
except:
    PASS
```

And here is your local_settings.py:

```
DEV_APPS = ('compressor',)
```

Comment: Simple and very straight forward. Just one question: wouldn't it be better to set `DEV_APPS = ()`. Then you cocatenate two tuples instead of adding `None` and `tupple`.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to rename the original `settings.py` (made by `./manage.py startproject`) into `base_settings.py`. This way all the baseline settings are in `base_settings.py`.

I will then create a new `settings.py` file that will only contain the needed environment-specific modifications and overrides from `base_settings.py`.

So, to answer your question using my approach, my `settings.py` will be like this:

```
from .base_settings import *

INSTALLED_APPS += ('compressor',)
```

Any necessary environment-specific setting will then be added in `settings.py`.

With this approach, I don't need to specify the `--settings` parameter when calling `./manage.py` or to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

Makes managing different environments much easier for me.

*Note: I use `git` and I add `settings.py` to `.gitignore` for this approach.*

Answer (score 0):

> Take add debug tools for example . 
>   Django==2.1.7

```py
# proj/settings/defaults.py
....

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    # apps
    'apps.document.apps.DocumentConfig',
]
```

```py
# proj/settings/dev.py

DEBUG = True
from .defaults import *

INSTALLED_APPS += ['debug_toolbar']
```

```py
# proj/urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns = [
                      path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
                  ] + urlpatterns
```

```sh
./manage.py runserver --settings=proj.settings.dev
```