# Weird deployment issue with Django and CoffeeScript to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, coffeescript, fabric, django-compressor

This is sort of a complex question so it will take a bit to explain.  I'm not looking for a direct answer so any advice would be good.  I have a Django app that uses a lot of CoffeeScript.  To compile the CoffeeScript in the project I am using the app `django-compressor`.  To use `django-compressor` I need to install `nmp` (node package manager).  Unfortunately, I can't install `npm` on Heroku.  Thus, I need to compile the CoffeeScript before it hits the Heroku servers.  So I did that by setting up `Fabric` which is seeming to work well.

I am running into a problem no because I can get the compiled CoffeeScript as a static file but the templates still have the `{% compress js %} *** {% endcompress %}` tags in them because `django-compressor` does not regenerate new templates until run time.

Thus I am looking for advice on how to deploy the app to get ride of the template tags so that the app can be deployed on Heroku.  I know it is a question with a lot of parts so any piece of advice would be super helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize it's quite an old question - hit it occasionally
Just in case, here's the way to deal:

http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#pre-compression

http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scenarios/#offline-compression

Answer (score 0):

you could also commit the manifest.json file that django compressor generates (I'm assuming you're using it in offline mode) and then it will know which template blocks go to which compiled js/css files